# How can I avoid method swizzling pollution through class hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

```
@interface TestView: UIView
@end
```

I want to replace `TestView`'s(inherited from UIView) `layoutSubviews` method for some particular reason. But don't want to effect the origin `UIView`'s lifecycle, just want it to work within class `TestView`.

I simply implement it like this:

```
@implementation TestView

+(void)load {
    Method a = class_getInstanceMethod(TestView.class, @selector(layoutSubviews));
    Method b = class_getInstanceMethod(TestView.class, @selector(customLayout));
    method_exchangeImplementations(a, b);
}
```

But something went wrong. It seems that UIWindow called `customLayout` too. I guess it's been polluted. How can I avoid that?

> IDE: xCode 8.2.1
>
> OS:  10.12.4

Here's the test code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface TestView: UIView

@end

@implementation TestView

+(void)load {
    Method a = class_getInstanceMethod(TestView.class, @selector(layoutSubviews));
    Method b = class_getInstanceMethod(TestView.class, @selector(customLayout));
    method_exchangeImplementations(a, b);
}


-(void) customLayout {
    [self customLayout];
}

-(instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor;
    return self;
}

@end


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    TestView* view = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Here's the runtime log:

```
2017-06-07 14:51:38.240 swizzleTest[37908:28470016] -[UIWindow customLayout]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc3d7009d00
2017-06-07 14:51:38.242 swizzleTest[37908:28470016] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWindow customLayout]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc3d7009d00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111450d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f00021e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001114c0f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113d6005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113d5b88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   swizzleTest                         0x000000010ea2b3fb -[TestView customLayout] + 43
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010f594ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    7   QuartzCore                          0x0000000114296bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    8   QuartzCore                          0x000000011428a440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    9   QuartzCore                          0x000000011428a2be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114218318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00000001142453ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114245d6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113f5267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113f51d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113d98a6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 454
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010f4c9aea -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010f4cfc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    18  swizzleTest                         0x000000010ea2b9af main + 111
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011240068d start + 1
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern found for swizzling in the docs is:

1. look up the method in the subclass

2a. If the method exists, swizzle

2b. If the method doesn't exist in the subclass (is inherited from a superclass), add the method as a new method.

Comment: Any link please?

Answer (score 0):

After I override `layoutSubviews` explicitly in `TestView` class it works.
Otherwise, `class_getInstanceMethod(TestView.class, @selector(layoutSubviews));` can only get `-[UIView layoutSubviews]` instead of `-[TestView layoutSubviews]`.

Modified code is as follows:

```
@implementation TestView

+(void)load {
    Method a = class_getInstanceMethod(TestView.class, @selector(layoutSubviews));
    Method b = class_getInstanceMethod(TestView.class, @selector(customLayout));
    method_exchangeImplementations(a, b);
}


-(void) customLayout {
    [self customLayout];
}

-(void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

-(instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor;
    return self;
}

@end
```